# How to prevent files from being uploaded with Multer unless they are images?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

As title says.

I looked everywhere, couldn't find an answer.

---

**CODE:**

```
var upload = multer({dest:"./public/images/uploads/", limits: {fileSize: 250000}}).single("image");
```

---

**PROBLEM**

This does not prevent me from uploading a pdf if I choose to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs state you should use fileFilter to possibly skip files for upload.
**fileFilter** (https://github.com/expressjs/multer#filefilter)

```
Set this to a function to control which files should be uploaded and which should be skipped. The function should look like this:

function fileFilter (req, file, cb) {

  // The function should call `cb` with a boolean
  // to indicate if the file should be accepted

  // To reject this file pass `false`, like so:
  cb(null, false)

  // To accept the file pass `true`, like so:
  cb(null, true)

  // You can always pass an error if something goes wrong:
  cb(new Error('I don\'t have a clue!'))

}
```

From the docs I would assume that the passed in `file` has a property `mimetype` (https://github.com/expressjs/multer#api). This could be a good hint for the decision if you want to skip.

**EDIT:**
this GH issues (https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/114#issuecomment-231591339) contains a good example for the usage. It's important to not only look at the file extension because this can easily be renamed but also take the mime-type into account.

```
const path = require('path');

multer({
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {

    var filetypes = /jpeg|jpg/;
    var mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
    var extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());

    if (mimetype && extname) {
      return cb(null, true);
    }
    cb("Error: File upload only supports the following filetypes - " + filetypes);
  }
});
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the hint ! But that's not a complete answer with an example that relates to my case :)

Comment: I do think this relates very well. Your linked github issues uses the same function (fileFilter). I would also prefer to check the mime-type since the file name extension can easily be wrong. Don't understand the down vote. I thought an extra if clause wouldn't be an issue. https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/114#issuecomment-231591339 :-)

Comment: you hadn't included this in your answer :/ How about you edit your answer ? :)